# Битрикс. Настройка веб-мессенджера

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!
Народ, помогите пожалуйста правильно настроить компонент веб-мессенджер, чтобы можно было создавать в нём групповой чат.

Разместил на отдельной странице компонент bitrix:im.messenger:

```
if ($arResult['ERROR_CODE'] == '')
{
    $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
            "bitrix:im.messenger",
            "custom",
            Array(
        "CONTEXT" => "LINES",
        "DESIGN" => "POPUP",
        "RECENT" => "Y",
        "CURRENT_TAB" => "35"
    ), false, Array("HIDE_ICONS" => "Y"));
}
```

Жму вверху значок "карандаш с квадратом", далее выбираю "закрытый чат". Появляется вверху строковое поле для поиска пользователей, которых нужно найти, чтобы добавить в этот чат. Но во никакие пользователи там не ищутся. Что с этим делать - пока не знаю. Может есть какой-либо другой способ создать групповой чат, используя компонент bitrix:im.messenger?

Скриншоты все прикладываю. Помогите пожалуйста. Редакция Битрикс: 18.5.180 (Корпоративный портал)

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]